# ¿Cómo recorrer un mapa desde un punto sin leerlo por completo todo en Java?

Tags: java

Un saludo a todos. Tengo la siguiente inquietud, que ignoro si sea posible al menos con mapas ordenados en Java (`TreeMap`). La idea es buscar si la llave del mapa cuenta con al menos un hijo (ej: primer hijo de "10" es "100", de "a", es "a1", etc.). Dado que le mapa es robusto y se consulta de forma recurrente, deseo mejorar los tiempos de respuesta que me da esta rutina:

```
public boolean hayHijo(Map mapa, String sLlave) {
if (mapa.isEmpty() || !mapa.containsKey(sLlave)) return false;
for (String sKey : mapa.keySet()) {
    if (sKey.length()==(sLlave.length()+1) && 
          (sKey.substring(0, sLlave.length())).equals(sLlave))
                  return true;
   }
  return false;
}
```

Las llaves de mapa son de la forma:

> {"1", "10", "100", "11", "110", "2", "a", "a1", "a10", etc.}.

La rutina recorre el mapa desde el principio hasta el final o hasta que encuentre la condición. Sin embargo, si el padre buscado está al final del mapa, el recorrido tiene que verificar antes todos los valores previos, lo que toma tiempo y retrasos en la respuesta. ¿Existe una forma de buscar el padre (la llave recibida por parámetro, por ejemplo la "a") y a partir de esa posición en el mapa, iniciar la búsqueda de la información? Gracias por la colaboración e información que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que usted menciona no sé si la estructura de datos adecuada para realizar el tipo de operaciones que desea sea un TreeMap de Java. Un TreeMap es una implementación de una estructura de datos en el que los elementos insertados son ordenados de acuerdo al orden natural de las llaves, es decir, un TreeMap en realidad no es árbol, sino un Map donde se usa un árbol por debajo para resolver la comparación entre los elementos.

Dado que un TreeMap retorna las llaves ordenadas de forma natural, usa la interfaz Comparable para determinar el orden apropiado. Por el código (dado que no hizo uso de tipos al declarar el Map) supongo que sus llaves son de tipo String. El orden natural de los String está determinado por el valor que retorne el método compareTo(). Traduciendo esto a lo que usted propone (orden-natural = verificar si tiene al menos un hijo), no es del todo claro que la estructura TreeMap soporte lo que usted quiere. Por otro lado, la implementación de un TreeMap se realiza con un [árbol rojo-negro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_rojo-negro), lo que garantiza que la búsqueda, inserción o eliminación de elementos tenga complejidad computacional O(lg n).

En últimas, la implementación de un TreeMap no le permite saber dado una llave K si esta 'tiene o no tiene hijos', en el sentido que todos los hijos conservarían el orden natural de los String (y pueden ser 'hijos' de esa llave), pero, dada la implementación de un árbol rojo-negro, otras llaves que conserven el orden natural pueden no ser hijas de esa 'llave'.

Mi sugerencia es que evalúe el uso de otra estructura de datos que le permita garantizar las mismas operaciones y sus elementos sí sean persistidos con la estructura que solicita. Por ejemplo, construir su propia implementación de árbol binario, que le garantiza también que la búsqueda, eliminación e inserción de datos tenga complejidad O(lg n).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que básicamente necesitas un iterador que te ayude a recorrer la estructura de datos en la forma que quieres.

Quizá debas heredar de la interfaz Iterator (un ejemplo [aqui](http://migranitodejava.blogspot.com.es/2011/06/iterator.html)), y construirte el tuyo propio, para dejarlo inicializado en la posición necesaria y que te devuelva los valores restantes en forma de array o algo parecido, para que te sea más cómodo operar sobre la estructura subyacente.